# Possible to have one OAuth 2.0 client for multiple Android apps on Firebase Auth?

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase project shared by over 30 Android apps. Every app has its own OAuth 2.0 client used for Google Login.

Now I hit the 30 apps per one project limit: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#app-per-project

The firebase support is unable to increase this limit.

Now my question is:

Is it possible to use one OAuth client for multiple Android apps? All these apps are signed with the same signing key (meaning that they all need the same SHA-1 fingerprint). They all have different app ids of course.